Camunda creating pods and docker comtainers? ERROR
I have recently deployed camunda on kubernetes with deployment yaml file in development environment. Its working fine and running. The issues i am getting is it creates docker containers along with camunda pods i.e kubernetes objects. It should only create kubernetes pods not docker containers along with it. I do not understand why its creating docker containers and these docker containers are consuming alot of space on hardware level.
Any help on this would be appreciated.
I am not sure what to do in this situation, and tried to troubleshoot it but couldn't. I am expecting that only camunda pods should be created when i apply deployment yaml file not docker containers along with the pods.
